# Start wercker job hourly

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, wercker

I've just started using [wercker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wercker) and I'd like a job to run regularly (e.g. daily, hourly).  I realize this may be an anti-pattern, but is it possible? My intent is not to keep the container running indefinitely, just that my workflow is executed on a particular interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a call to the [Wercker API](http://devcenter.wercker.com/api/getting-started/authentication.html) to [trigger a build](http://devcenter.wercker.com/api/endpoints/builds.html#trigger-a-build) for any project which is set up already in Wercker.

So maybe set up a cron job somewhere that uses curl to make the right API call?